# Which internal file in g++ contain the information about compile time calculation of program?

Tags: gcc, c++11, g++, clang

This is about finding the Fibonacci number using recursive approach which I had asked
in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22645551/2724703).  Using one of the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22645853/2724703)(answered), the run time taken 
by the program was almost 0. I attach the program in GDB and check the assembly instruction
and found the following:

```
#include<iostream>
template<size_t N>
struct fibonacci:std::integral_constant<size_t,fibonacci<N-1>{}+fibonacci<N-2>{}>{};
template<> struct fibonacci<1> : std::integral_constant<size_t,1> {};
template<> struct fibonacci<0> : std::integral_constant<size_t,0> {};
int main() {
    int out = 0;
    constexpr int number = 40;
    out = fibonacci<number>();
    std::cout<<"Fibonacci Series Of "<<number<<" is "<<out<<std::endl;
}
```

I have compiled my program using following flags and assembly instruction
of my program is as:

> $g++ -g -gdwarf-2 -Wall -fdump-tree-all  -std=c++11 fibonacci.cpp -o
>   fibcpp

```
(gdb) disassemble main
   Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x0000000000400890 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400891 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400894 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
  0x0000000000400898 <+8>:  movl   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x000000000040089f <+15>:    movl   $0x28,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x00000000004008a6 <+22>:    lea    -0x9(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004008aa <+26>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
=>  0x00000000004008ad <+29>:   callq  0x400952 <std::integral_constant<unsigned long, 102334155ul>::operator unsigned long() const>
   0x00000000004008b2 <+34>:    mov    %eax,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004008b5 <+37>:    mov    $0x400a15,%esi
```

we can see that(on the arrowed==>) 102334155 is there which is fibonacci(40). This indicates that indeed all calculation has happened in the compile time.

When we compile our program and put extra flag(**-fdump-tree-all**), we get many 
internal files and normally(fibonacci.gimple) files are the one where normally template
instantiated code would go.  However in this case I did not find anything 
related to this calculation in fibonacci.gimple file.

My question is in which file g++ does calculate and store these information?. My aim over here is to understand more about compile time calculation/manipulation which happens in C++ program.

Comment: I believe template instantiation is performed in the front-end, there is no file that would contains a code that execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you disassembly it seems, that the "method" `operator unsigned long()` is called and not inlined. When you look at its disassembly, you should see the actual returned value. It is the instantiation of `integral_constant<>::operator value_type()` with `size_t` = `unsigned long` as `value_type`.

But you might already know all that... You want to actually see it. The message https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2011-06/msg00110.html suggests, that others thought about an `-ftrace-template-instantiation` option, but no one implemented it, yet.

EDIT: There is lots of information about debugging and tracing templates in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818281/profiling-template-metaprogram-compilation-time).