# non datatype template parameter, more specialization generated?

Tags: c++, instantiation

My Code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template <typename T, int X>

class Test
{
   private:
    T container[X];
   public:
    void printSize();

};
template <typename T, int X>
void Test<T,X>::printSize()
{
    cout <<"Container Size = "<<X <<endl;
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    Test<int, 20> t;
    Test<int, 30> t1;

    t.printSize();
    t1.printSize();
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**

1. How many specialization will get generated?. 
    If I understand correctly , it generates two specializations one is for `<int, 20>`  and another is for `<int, 30>`. Kindly Correct if my understanding is wrong?
2. Is there any way to see/check the number of specializations generated by any reverse engineering?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448094/can-we-see-the-template-instantiated-code-by-c-compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) yes, two instantiations will be generated by the **compiler**, but the **linker** might merge functions with identical generated code (using whole program optimization e.g.), which is a cute way to reduce code bloat.

2) see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11403417/819272) where it is explained how gcc can generate template instantiation output.

Answer (score 3):

There are not *specializations* here, only *instantiations* ([this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914642/difference-between-instantiation-and-specialization-in-c-templates) explains the difference). This code generates two instantiations of the class template `Test`.

Comment: I think when saying specializations he meant generated-classes. i actually dont understand why two (classes) are created, if its still an int in both times.

Comment: @Infested the value of `X` differs

Comment: @rhalbersma ive noticed that, but its still an int. how would i write it so the "X" part doesnt make a difference?

Comment: @Infested: If you don't want the `X` to make a difference, make it a parameter to the constructor of `Test`. Then you cannot have a statically sized array as member though. This is the semantic difference between `std::array` and `std::vector`.

Comment: @BjörnPollex that i know also, but is there a way to hold two types in the template and with one not making a difference for different values? lets say LIST<T> and you create LIST<int> t1; LIST<int> t2; it will not generate LIST<int> twice, only instantiate t1 and t2 twice.

Comment: @Infested Because in your case, the template arguments are the same: `int`. Templates can have type parameters as well as non-type parameters. `X` is a non-type parameter, which means that each value of `X` creates a different instantiation (just like each different type used as the argument for a type parameter creates a different instantiation).

Comment: @Angew so if i were to write template <typename T, int> thatd be ok, and only generating for each T ?

Comment: @Infested It's as Björn Pollox states: if you want to have a compile-time `container[X]` then you will get 2 instantiations, no matter what. If you are OK with a runtime sized vector, then you only  need 1.

Comment: @Infested `template <typename T, int>` has two template parameters: a type parameter (named T) and a non-type int parameter (unnamed). Different integer values used as arguments for the non-type parameter will generate different instantiations. *Just like with any other template arguments.*

Comment: @Angew thats what i was asking, so it doesnt make two classes that way.

Comment: @Infested **Yes, it does generate two.** If you have `template <typename T, int> struct S;`, then `S<char, 10>` and `S<char, 11>` are two **absolutely distinct** classes.

Answer (score 0):

a)  There are 2 instances of specialization get created in your example.

b)There is no builtin method to support number of specialization generated for a class.
If its your project you can add static count.
If you want you can write your own reference count mechanism for your class.
Increment static count in our constructor.

```
static int created = 0;
static int alive = 0;
class Test
{
counter()
    {
        created++;
        alive++;
    }
~counter()
{
  created--;
}
//Rest of class
};
```

Comment: Your counter would count the number of instances of the class, not instantiations of the template.